# Add entry_points to setuptools in package being install

Tags: python, setuptools, entry-point, fsspec

I have a python package [fsspec](https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec). This library provides a way to register external filesystem ([backend integration](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html#implementing-a-backend)). One way to register the required filesystem is to add it to the entry_points in setuptools.

To accomplish the task, we can manually add the entry_points in the setup.py and then install the package. But what I am looking for is a way to programmatically make the entry pre/post installation of the fsspec package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a simple way to update the metadata that normally gets written into your system during a package install. Digging through the code of `setuptools` or `importlib.metadata` might tell you how. It may be, that the `Distribution` object exposed by metadata can be edited in memory.
The point of the approach is, that fsspec does not need to import anything (aside from `importlib.metadata` itself) to know what extra implementations are available.

However, you might get far enough by using [`fsspec.register_implementation`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.registry.register_implementation), which is be done dynamically at runtime. The only downside is, that your package will need to be imported and the function called *before* you try to access the protocol it provides.

Comment: I don't want users to import and call the function before trying to access the protocols i.e the register_implementation flow. I want to limit the users in writing multiple lines of code. In my case, entry_points makes more sense.

Comment: OK, so if you find a way to register entrypoints programmatically, please edit here, I would be interested to find out too.